# How to draw a vertical line on image in php

Tags: php, line, draw, image

i am making an antibot that displays different pictures, and asks the user to click on a specific picture. However, i would like some small random change to be made to the picture each time, so that software could not analyze and determine which picture is beeing displayed...

I would like one horizontal and one vertical line to be added at random coordinates with random color to the picture each time, then display the picture using get_file_contents and header.

Hope this makes sense...  I would not want the changes to be saved to the picture, but only displayed to the user... I am using file_get_contents and header to display the picture, like this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$image = "images/".$id . ".jpg";
$content = file_get_contents($image); 
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $content;
exit()
```

Thanks...

Comment: Use [PHPs GD extension](http://php.net/manual/de/book.image.php) to modify the output on-the-fly. Also note that just some lines aren't enough to divert OCR bots for captchas. (It works in your case as long as your site is obscure enough and nobody bothers to fit your form fields.)

Answer (score 0):

Using GD within PHP would allow you to do this

```
http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php
```

create a file called image.php

From the php manual:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: image/png");
$string = $_GET['text'];
$im     = imagecreatefrompng("images/button1.png");
$orange = imagecolorallocate($im, 220, 210, 60);
$px     = (imagesx($im) - 7.5 * strlen($string)) / 2;
imagestring($im, 3, $px, 9, $string, $orange);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

You could add a line by using the imageline function

```
<?php

header("Content-type: image/png");
$string = $_GET['text'];
$im     = imagecreatefrompng("images/button1.png");
$orange = imagecolorallocate($im, 220, 210, 60);
$px     = (imagesx($im) - 7.5 * strlen($string)) / 2;
imagestring($im, 3, $px, 9, $string, $orange);
imageline($im, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $orange);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many [PHP GD functions available to achive this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php)  I think below code snippet may help you

```
<?php

$im = imagecreatefrompng("images/yourImage.png");
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);

// Draw a vertical dashed line
imagedashedline($im, 50, 25, 50, 75, $white);

// Save the image
imagepng($im, './imagewithdashedline.png');
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

reference [PHP GD imagedashedline function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagedashedline.php)